# What is this inside an erb template [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm seeing code like this inside of an erb template:

```
<% hook :admin_footer_scripts do -%>
```

What exactly is hook? is it a standard method within ActionView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a helper method defined in your application. Look in `app/helpers/application.rb` or in the `app/helpers/` directory for a ruby file named like the controller which renders that view

Answer (score 0):

Just from what it looks like I'd say it's a way to allow the controller to add code the the page. But bgj is right. Look in your helper files.